# Django: How to associate a comment to its corresponding OP in the HTML template?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I have designed a simplistic posting and comment system where each postcomment object is associated with its corresponding newpost object using foreign key. My problem is that the comments in the template aren’t showing under their corresponding newpost object. For example, if there are a total of 3 newposts and 3 comments under each post for a total of 9 comments, the template displays all 9 comments under each 3 posts (for a total of 27 comments). I need help figuring out how to correctly associate each comment with its corresponding post and not just loop through my ‘allcomments’ field under each post. Thanks for any help and hints.

```
postset = pagename.newpost_set.all().order_by('-postdate') #i use this to get a queryset of all posts on the selected page and order them so newest posts show up at the top
allposts = newpost.objects.filter(newposttag=‘userpage’) #i use this to get a queryset of all posts on the corresponding user’s page for the next line, this might seem redundant after the above, but it works because the postset is what I end up using in the template. 
 allcomments = postcomment.objects.filter(commenttag=allposts) #i use this to get a queryset of all the comments from each post in the ‘allposts’ queryset
```

Here is my template for displaying the above information that I have acquired

```
{% for postset in postset %}
    <br>{{ postset.postcontent }} {{postset.postdate }} - {{ postset.postlikes }} likes <a href="/enterlink/comment">Comment</a></br>
    {% for allcomments in allcomments %}
    <br> {{ allcomments.comment }} {{allcomments.postcommentdate }} - {{ allcomments.commentlikes}}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about updating your template as follows:

```
{% for post in postset %}
    <br>{{ post.postcontent }} {{post.postdate }} - {{ post.postlikes }} likes <a href="/enterlink/comment">Comment</a></br>

    {% for comment in post.postcomment_set.all %}
        <br> {{ comment.comment }} {{comment.postcommentdate }} - {{ comment.commentlikes}} </br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This way, you iterate over your posts and for each post, you retrieve the comments related to that post through the `post.postcomment_set.all` expression.

Please let me know if that helps you.

ps: I don't think that you need those three queries in your view though.

Comment: can you briefly explain the logic behind it? I am struggling to understand how it's fundamentally different than what I had before and why it would solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: In your template, you run the inner for loop on `allcomments` for each post. That was the main problem there. Btw, I just edited the variable names to make it more clear.

Comment: And also, I assume that in your Comment model, you have a field something like `post = models.ForeignKey(newpost)`

Comment: ... why don't you name your models PascalCase such as `Post` and `Comment`?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's how I attach each comment to its corresponding newpost. 
Thanks, I think I get it a bit now. So does this mean that before this part of the template can work I have to store the 'post.postcomment_set.all()' in a variable and return that queryset in the 'render' portion of my views.py? Sorry for the noob question, this is my first django app.

Comment: No problem. So, in your view, you just need to pass the `postset` to the template, calculated in your code: `postset = pagename.newpost_set.all().order_by('-postdate')` The comments will be retrieved in your template by the `post.postcomment_set.all` call.

Comment: Ah, I got it working fine now. Thank you for all your help. That ended up being way easier to implement than I thought.